# C++ Method chaining causes destructor to be called twice

Tags: c++, destructor, method-chaining

I have simple c++ program which uses method chaining and I noticed that destructor is called twice when used in chain call only. This happens only if chain call contain constructor as well. If called separately destructor is called only once.

Code is below:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo()   { cout << "-- constructor " << this << endl; }
    ~Foo () { cout << "-- destructor  " << this << endl; };

    Foo& bar() {
        cout << "---- bar call  " << this << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    cout << "starting test 1" << endl;
    {
        Foo f = Foo();
    }
    cout << "ending test 1"   << endl << endl;
    cout << "starting test 2" << endl;
    {
        Foo f = Foo().bar();
    }
    cout << "ending test 2"   << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Result of this application is following:

```
starting test 1
-- constructor 0x7ffd008e005f
-- destructor  0x7ffd008e005f
ending test 1

starting test 2
-- constructor 0x7ffd008e005f
---- bar call  0x7ffd008e005f
-- destructor  0x7ffd008e005f
-- destructor  0x7ffd008e005f
ending test 2
```

Is this standard behavior (if so, why is that?) or did I make some mistake? Can I prevent this?

Comment: Add the copy constructor and assignment operator to see what is going one

Comment: The copy mentioned in all answers below is [elided](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) in the first case. If you compile with `g++ -fno-elide-constructors` you'll see 2 destructors being invoked.

Comment: Well that pretty interesting. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't the issue, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Foo f = Foo().bar();` also calls the *copy constructor* of `Foo`, which is currently the one the compiler generates and so doesn't output anything to the console. *That's* why it looks like you're calling more destructors than constructors.

You could write `const Foo& f = Foo().bar();` to obviate a copy. Using a `const` also extends the lifetime of the anonymous temporary, which is nice.

Answer (score 5):

Note that there are two objects of type `Foo` involved in the line:

```
Foo f = Foo().bar();
    ^----------------this one
        ^------------and this one
```

however, one is created via the constructor and the other one via the copy constructor. And thats why you get only one line printed for construction and two for destruction. Everything is fine with the code, you just have to implement the copy constructor to see consistent output.

Answer (score 5):

There is another constructor that you have not implemented by yourself. The copy constructor.

Your call `Foo f = Foo().bar();` could be written as `Foo tmp = Foo(); Foo f = tmp.bar();`

Only the instantiation of your `tmp` object will call your constructor. The constructor called for `f` is the automatically genererated copy-constructor.

This should give you some better output:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() { cout << "-- constructor " << this << endl; }
    Foo(const Foo& f) { cout << "-- copy-constructor " << this << endl; }
    ~Foo() { cout << "-- destructor  " << this << endl; };

    Foo& bar() {
        cout << "---- bar call  " << this << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    cout << "starting test 1" << endl;
    {
        Foo f = Foo();
    }
    cout << "ending test 1" << endl << endl;
    cout << "starting test 2" << endl;
    {
        Foo f = Foo().bar();
    }
    cout << "ending test 2" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

--

```
starting test 1
-- constructor 000000EC09CFF944
-- destructor  000000EC09CFF944
ending test 1

starting test 2
-- constructor 000000EC09CFFA44
---- bar call  000000EC09CFFA44
-- copy-constructor 000000EC09CFF964
-- destructor  000000EC09CFFA44
-- destructor  000000EC09CFF964
ending test 2
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the expected behavior. Even though you return a reference from `bar` you are not using it.

```
Foo f = Foo().bar();
```

captures the return value by value so you make a copy.  This means that the `Foo` from `Foo()` is destroyed at the end of the expression and the copy of it you make into `f` is destroyed when you exit the scope.